# What does opengl es 2 doesn't have set matrix mode method?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to develop using `opengles2` in android platform. But i can't find `glMatrixMode` method in `GLES2/gl2.h` header file, but i can find it in `GLES/gl.h`. Should i include `gl.h` at the same time i include `gl2.h`? Is matrix mode necessary in opengles2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no matrix stack in OpenGL-ES-2. It has been removed entirely. The same goes for modern OpenGL (OpenGL-3 core and later).

You're supposed to manage matrices yourself, the way every serious 3D graphics application does for years. The matrix stack of <=OpenGL-2.1 and OpenGL-ES-1 never was feature complete and is cumbersome to work with. Good riddance.

There are a number of libraries that implement 3D graphics matrix math. Google for "GLM", "Eigen" or "linmath.h"

Comment: So does it means i don't need to care about the matrix mode any more? If i use the provided api to draw pictures, then it always stay at the right matrix mode?

Comment: @user674199: There is no longer a matrix mode. Kind of makes sense, because you've to supply a vertex shader anyway, and the semantics of any matrix you supply is completely defined by the shader. Normally you'll supply 3 matrices: a modelview, a projection and a normal transformation matrix (the normal transformation is the inverse transpose of the modelview).

Comment: I'll throw my client side side routines into the ring: [matrix.h](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs442/util/matrix.h), [matrix.c](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs442/util/matrix.c). Use `glUniformMatrix4fv` to load your matrix into GL for your shaders to use.

Comment: Well, I already mentioned my "libmath.h" which is a static inline header only sort-of library. https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h